# Is the run-queue column in vmstat a sum of values or just one measurement?

Tags: vmstat

When I run vmstat on a RHEL 6.6 machine with a time interval I sometimes see the run-queue column jump to "high" values.
I know the first line reported by vmstat is averages since the machine booted but what about the following lines?
Is the run-queue column the current value when the output line was generated or the sum of processes that has been on the run-queue since the previous output was generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Fine Manual Page for vmstat says, almost in passing:

> The process and memory reports are instantaneous in either case.

Which means that it's the current value when the output line was generated.